# Wix bootstrapper doesn't call the msi file during uninstall if DisplayInternalUI="yes"

Tags: wix, uninstallation, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

I have an existing wix msi project with full fledged UI. I created a wix bundle and referenced the msi project in this bootstrapper project.It installs the msi perfectly but during uninstall it doesn't call the msi when DisplayInternalUI="yes" for the msi package.But when the DisplayInternalUI="no" for msi, it uninstalls correctly by calling the msi package.How to get around this issue.As, I can't set the DisplayInternalUI to no, as I want msi UI to be displayed during install.Is there a way to turn DisplayInternalUI to no during uninstall and to yes during install.Here is my bundle code:

```
<Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="Name" UpgradeCode="GUID"  >
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication      SuppressOptionsUI="yes"  LicenseUrl="" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <util:RegistrySearch Id="Office2007_Installed" Variable="OFFICE2007"  Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\InstallRoot" Result="exists" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTOR_Installed" Variable="VSTOR40"  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R" Result="exists" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTOR_Installed1" Variable="VSTOR40_1"  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4" Result="exists" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTOR_Installed2" Variable="VSTOR40_2"  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4" Result="exists" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTOR_Installed3" Variable="VSTOR40_3"  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R" Result="exists" />

        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
      <ExePackage  Id="INSTALLVSTO" SourceFile="vstor_redist.exe"  Vital="yes"  Compressed="no" Permanent="yes" 
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="VSTOR40 OR VSTOR40_1 OR VSTOR40_2 OR VSTOR40_3"
                  InstallCondition="NOT (VSTOR40 OR VSTOR40_1 OR VSTOR40_2 OR VSTOR40_3)" />
      <RollbackBoundary />

         <MsiPackage  Compressed="yes"   SourceFile="$(var.Msi Project name.TargetPath)" Vital="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Cache="no">

        </MsiPackage>   


        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
```

And here is the Product.wxs file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <?define ProductName = "Outlook Plug-In"?>
  <?define ProductVersion = "4.0.8.7"?>

  <Product Id="81f4a93f-ee3f-438d-a836-741666112715" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="ABC" UpgradeCode="{B9080C51-8F85-4D5B-9387-DE942A43C985}" >
    <!--InstallScope to hide Administrator login on installation-->
    <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"  InstallScope="perMachine"/>
    <Binary Id="SummaryA" SourceFile="Bitmap\Summary.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="CustomAction_OutlookPlugin" SourceFile="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Installer_CustomActions\bin\$(var.Configuration)\Installer_CustomActions.CA.dll" />
    <Binary Id="SummaryB" SourceFile="Bitmap\MaintienanceSum.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="Bmp_Install" SourceFile="Bitmap\Destination.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="LicdialogBmp" SourceFile="Bitmap\License.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="Banner" SourceFile="Bitmap\bannrbmp.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="ProgressA" SourceFile="Bitmap\Installation.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="ProgressB" SourceFile="Bitmap\MaintienancePro.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="VerifyReadyDlgA" SourceFile="Bitmap\InstallationType.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="VerifyReadyDlgB" SourceFile="Bitmap\MaintienanceIns.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="Bmp_Dialog" SourceFile="Bitmap\Introduction.bmp" />
    <Binary Id="Maintienance" SourceFile="Bitmap\Maintienance.bmp" />
    <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Resources\ECM_Icon_v1.ico"/>
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
    <Property Id="OFFICE2007"  Value="0"/>
    <Property Id="SectionName"/>

     <Property Id="OFFICE_2007_32" >
      <RegistrySearch Id="Office32"   Win64="no"  Name ="Path"  Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\InstallRoot" Type="raw" />
    </Property>
    <Property Id="OFFICE_2007_64">
      <RegistrySearch   Id="Office64" Win64="yes" Name="Path" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\InstallRoot" Type="raw" >
      </RegistrySearch>
    </Property>

    <Property Id="PluginVersion" Value="$(var.ProductVersion)"/>
    <Property Id="PluginDescription" Value="Outlook Plug-In"/>
    <Property Id="FriendlyName" Value="Outlook Addin($(var.ProductVersion))"/>
    <Property Id="VSTOName" Value="CustomPane_outlookAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"/>
    <!--Property Section-->
    <!--To Check NETFRAMEWORK-->
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />
    <Condition Message='This setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.'>
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
    </Condition>
    <!--To Check Upgrade-->
    <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
    <Property Id="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" Secure="yes" />
    <!--For LocalAppData-->
    <Property Id="REMEMBERME">
      <RegistrySearch Id="RememberProperty" Root="HKCU"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Wix\DemoRememberProperty"
            Name="Remembered" Type="raw"/>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="REMEMBERME1">
      <RegistrySearch Id="RememberProperty1" Root="HKCU"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Wix\DemoRememberProperty1"
            Name="Remembered1" Type="raw"/>
    </Property>
    <!--Set Initial directory browseproperty-->
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION"/>
    <Property Id="SETALLUSERS"/>
    <!--<SetProperty Id="SETALLUSERS" Before="AppSearch" Value="{}">
    </SetProperty>-->

    <!-- Default configuration values -->


    <Property Id="SERVICEURL">Server Url/Environment</Property>

    <Property Id="GETALLUSERS">
      <RegistrySearch Id="GETALLUSERSRegistry" Type="raw"
              Root='HKLM' Key='Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\OutlookAddin' Name='Manifest'/>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="GETPERUSERS">
      <RegistrySearch Id="GETPERUSERSRegistry" Type="raw"
              Root='HKCU' Key='Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\OutlookAddin' Name='Manifest'/>
    </Property>

    <Feature Id="CustomPane_outlookAddIn" Title="Outlook Addin" Level="1" >
      <Component Id="FOLDER" Guid="*" DiskId="1" Directory="ABC" >
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Wix\DemoRememberProperty" Name="Remembered1" Value="[REMEMBERME1]" Type="string" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="CleanupFolder" On="uninstall" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="ProductFiles" Guid="9bb98af7-870b-4ce6-b2be-fd42203528ec" DiskId="1" Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' >
        <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
          <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
        </CreateFolder>
        <File Id="CustomPane_outlookAddIn_dll" Name="CustomPane_outlookAddIn.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\CustomPane_outlookAddIn.dll" />
        <File Id="CustomPane_outlookAddIn_dll_manifest" Name="CustomPane_outlookAddIn.dll.manifest" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\CustomPane_outlookAddIn.dll.manifest" />
        <File Id="CustomPane_outlookAddIn_vsto" Name="CustomPane_outlookAddIn.vsto" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\CustomPane_outlookAddIn.vsto" />
        <File Id="libeay32_dll" Name="libeay32.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Third Party Libs\libeay32.dll" />
        <File Id="libgcc_s_dw2_1_dll" Name="libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Third Party Libs\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" />
        <File Id="ssleay32_dll" Name="ssleay32.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Third Party Libs\ssleay32.dll" />
        <File Id="wkhtmltopdf_exe" Name="wkhtmltopdf.exe" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Third Party Libs\wkhtmltopdf.exe" />
        <File Id="OutlookGridControl_dll" Name="OutlookGridControl.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\OutlookGridControl.dll" />
        <File Id="UtilityClassess_dll" Name="UtilityClasses.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\UtilityClasses.dll" />
        <File Id="OneDriveAPI_dll" Name="OneDriveAPI.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\OneDriveAPI.dll" />
        <File Id="BoxAPI_dll" Name="BoxAPI.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\BoxAPI.dll" />
        <File Id="ZIP_dll" Name="Ionic.Zip.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\Ionic.Zip.dll" />
        <File Id="DropBoxAPI_dll" Name="DropBoxLibrary.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\DropBoxLibrary.dll" />
        <File Id="ProjectFolderOrder_xml" Name="ProjectFolderOrders.xml" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\Third Party Libs\ProjectFolderOrders.xml" />
        <File Id="Outlook_4_Utilities_dll" Name="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities.dll" />
        <File Id="Common_4_Utilities_dll" Name="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" />
        <!--<File Id="RestSharp_dll" Name="RestSharp.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\RestSharp.dll" />-->
        <File Id="JSON_dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
        <File Id="VSDNETCFG_dll" Name="VSDNETCFG.dll.config" Source=".\Binaryf\VSDNETCFG.dll.config" />
        <File Id="CUSTOMPANE_OUTLOOKADDIN_DLL_CONFIG" Name="CustomPane_outlookAddIn.dll.config" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\CustomPane_outlookAddIn.dll.config"/>
        <File Id="shell32_dll" Name="Interop.Shell32.dll" Source="..\..\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\CustomPane_outlookAddIn\bin\$(var.Build)\Interop.Shell32.dll" />



        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Wix\DemoRememberProperty" Name="Remembered" Value="[REMEMBERME]" Type="string" KeyPath="yes"/>

        <RemoveFolder Id="CleanupApplicationFolder" On="uninstall"    />
      </Component>


      <Component Id="CurrentMachineEntry" Guid="*" Directory="TARGETDIR">
        <Condition>NOT SETALLUSERS</Condition>
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\OutlookAddin" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="[PluginDescription]" />
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="FriendlyName" Value="[FriendlyName]" />
          <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="3" />
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Manifest" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION][VSTOName]" />
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="TEst" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION][VSTOName]" />
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="LocalMachineEntry" Guid="*" Directory="TARGETDIR" >
        <Condition  > SETALLUSERS AND NOT(OFFICE_2007_32 OR OFFICE_2007_64)  </Condition>
        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\OutlookAddin"   Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="[PluginDescription]" />
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="FriendlyName" Value="[FriendlyName]" />
          <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="3" />
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Manifest" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION][VSTOName]" />

        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>

    </Feature>


    <!--Remove older versions but do not overwrite newer versions.-->
    <Upgrade Id="{B9080C51-8F85-4D5B-9387-DE942A43C985}">
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" OnlyDetect="no" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes" IncludeMinimum="no" />
    </Upgrade>
    <CustomAction Id="CANCELNEWERVERSION"  Error="Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed." />


    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CANCELNEWERVERSION" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERPRODUCTFOUND AND NOT Installed</Custom>
      <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />

    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <!--Check the PRogram File in installation directory path.-->
    <CustomAction Id="Verify_INSTALLDIR" Script="vbscript">
      <![CDATA[
            Dim properties
            properties = Split(Session.Property("INSTALLLOCATION"), "\")
            If properties(1)="Program Files" Or properties(1)="Program Files (x86)" Then      
                MsgBox "You have selected Program Files as installation base folder."
            End If
            ]]>
    </CustomAction>
    <CustomAction Id="ALLUSERVerify" Script="vbscript">
      <![CDATA[
            Dim prop            
            prop = Session.Property("SETALLUSERS")
            If prop="1" Then      
                MsgBox "You must be an Administrator for this option to install correctly."
            End If
            ]]>
    </CustomAction>

    <!--Run Installer Class.-->
    <!--<Binary Id="InstallUtil" SourceFile="$(env.windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtilLib.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="Install" BinaryKey="InstallUtil" DllEntry="ManagedInstall" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />-->
    <!--<CustomAction Id="InstallSetPro" Property="Install" Value='/installtype=notransaction /action=install /LogFile= /sectionName="Install" /serviceUrl="[SERVICEURL]" "[#CustomPane_outlookAddIn_dll]" "[#VSDNETCFG_dll]"' />-->
    <!--<CustomAction Id="Uninstall" BinaryKey="InstallUtil" DllEntry="ManagedInstall" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />-->
    <CustomAction Id="UninstallSetPro"   Execute="immediate" Property="SectionName"  Value="Uninstall" />
    <CustomAction Id="InstallSetPro" Execute="immediate" Property="SectionName" Value="Install" />
    <CustomAction Id="Install" Return="check"  Execute="immediate"  BinaryKey="CustomAction_OutlookPlugin"  DllEntry="RegistryInstall"   />
    <CustomAction Id="Uninstall" Return="check"  Execute="immediate"  BinaryKey="CustomAction_OutlookPlugin"  DllEntry="RegistryInstall"   />
    <CustomAction Id="CopyOrderingFile" Return="check"  Execute="immediate"  BinaryKey="CustomAction_OutlookPlugin"  DllEntry="CopyOrderingFile"  />
    <!--<CustomAction Id="CheckForOffice2007" Return="check"  Execute="immediate"  BinaryKey="CustomAction_OutlookPlugin"  DllEntry="isOffice2007"  />-->

    <InstallExecuteSequence>

      <!--<Custom Action="CheckForOffice2007" Before="AllocateRegistrySpace" >$ProductFiles&gt;2</Custom>-->
      <Custom Action="InstallSetPro" After="WriteRegistryValues" >$ProductFiles&gt;2</Custom>
      <Custom Action="Install" After="InstallSetPro">$ProductFiles&gt;2</Custom>
      <Custom Action="CopyOrderingFile"  After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <!--<Custom Action="UninstallSetPro" After="MsiUnpublishAssemblies">$ProductFiles=2</Custom>-->
      <Custom Action="UninstallSetPro" After="MsiUnpublishAssemblies" > $ProductFiles=2</Custom>
      <Custom Action="Uninstall" After="UninstallSetPro">$ProductFiles=2</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <CustomAction Id="SetProductName" Property="ProductName" Value="Outlook Plug-In" Execute="immediate" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetProductName" Before="FindRelatedProducts">1</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <CustomAction Id="CANCELPERUSER"  Error="Product with same name already installed with per-machine setting.You are installing with per-user setting which is not allowed.Please uninstall the installed version and retry." />
    <CustomAction Id="CANCELALLUSER"  Error="Product with same name already installed with per-user setting.You are installing with per-machine setting which is not allowed.Please uninstall the installed version and retry." />
    <CustomAction Id="CANCELALLUSERWITHOUT" Error="You need administrative rights to Install with 'ALL Users' setting."/>

    <CustomAction Id="SETALLUSERSATREMOVE" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1" Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="SETPERUSERSATREMOVE" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="{}" Execute="immediate" />
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="SETALLUSERSATREMOVE" After="CostFinalize">GETALLUSERS AND Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action="SETPERUSERSATREMOVE" After="SETALLUSERSATREMOVE">GETPERUSERS AND Installed</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>

    <UIRef Id="My_InstallDir" />
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="simple.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="ABC" Name="AC">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Outlook Plug-In"/>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Comment: After analysing the logs, I found that, when DisplayInternalUI=“no” and it uninstalls correctly, it shows "Detected package: CMiC_Outlook_Addin.msi, state: Present". But when it is unsuccessfull it shows "Detected package: CMiC_Outlook_Addin.msi, state: Absent".

Answer (score 0):

WiX suppresses the internal MSI UI during uninstallation or repair. It by default shows a basic UI. However, it should still uninstall correctly.

Comment: I know it doesn't show UI during uninstall.But, for some reason it doesn't detect msi package during uninstall when DisplayInternalUI=“yes”

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problem a little more. Is the uninstaller not uninstalling the MSI correctly? `DisplayInternalUI="yes"` should not affect the uninstallation.

Comment: It is not calling the msi at all.In logs it shows msi state as absent.But when I run the bootstrapper with displayinternalui = no, it shows the state as present.

Comment: That is very weird. I am guessing that there might be something missing in your MSI wxs file. Are you setting the Product Id? Can you share its code too?

Comment: I am setting the Product ID

Comment: I have pretty much an identical setup. A simple bootstrapper that checks  and installs a few prerequisites and then calls a MSI with `DisplayInternalUI="yes"`. The only thing that I can really see that is different is that I am not setting the Product Id in the MSI. I have `Product Id="*"`. However, that probably should not affect uninstallation.